# How to run swing(.jar) files in micros POS 3700?

Tags: java, swing, point-of-sale, pos

I have made one swing .jar file with the User interface. I don't have any micros POS 3700. I wanted to know how my file will execute?

Comment: Isn't micros POS 3700 is a software?

Comment: am not sure about that. Because I think Oracle MICROS POS Systems that means it has OS and hardware like android phones, Tablets, Ipad for there own purpose. I actually want to fetch the data and update it from the webserver.

Comment: Perhaps these are the subjects of the question. [Oracle/Micros 3700](http://www.infinitypos.com/products/micros-3700/), [Industries/Food and Beverage/Restaurant POS Systems/Oracle MICROS RES 3700 POS System](https://www.oracle.com/industries/food-beverage/restaurant-pos-systems/res-3700/), [Oracle MICROS POS Systems](https://www.oracle.com/industries/micros/) Why not ask these vendors and resellers?